# How and where can I monetise my application?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I am currently publishing Android apps on Google Play and the Amazon Appstore.
Are you going to provide a similiar place to market apps?

- If so, is there some kind of Digital Rights Management provided or any
  other solution preventing unauthorised use?
- Is the source code some how protected or is everything open source?

Comment: I don't understand why this question is down voted? This is ubuntu related question? Isnt it?

Comment: @AbhijitNavale It's just information already easily accessible on the ubuntu.com web site. I believe the downvotes are for the expected "research effort" not being met.

Answer (score 1):

The bottom of the [Ubuntu mobile - Get started](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/) page mentions several links about [publising](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/).

There:

> You’ll also need to choose a licence (including open source and proprietary software).

and

> [Find out more about the packaging requirements ›](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/my-apps-packages/)

And even most useful perhaps: [Commercial Software FAQs](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/commercial-software-faqs/)

Will just provide the information that you need. Keep in mind that Ubuntu Mobile OS will be a full Ubuntu OS in terms of software distribution.

Comment: Sorry for not checking the already available infos, I got too excited after watching Mark Shuttleworth on YouTube. I think a license check of a paid app should be built into the OS and provided to the app through a simple API call, and not developed for each app separately. Ubuntu could then capatilise on a major flaw of Android. The payment via PayPal is ok, but expensive: 2.99 - 0.39 PayPal fees (0.30+3%)=2.60*80%=2.08 before VAT, thats 69% of the list price for the developer which equals the Google and Amazon Share with this example. I am a pro and I want to get paid for my efforts.

Comment: @Stefan This is not the right site to complain, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can publish your app in ubuntu software center
2. No ubuntu does not provide built in drm support, You have to implement one for your app
3. Source code of what? If you mean source code of ubuntu mobile, It will available soon. If you mean source code of your app, Open sourcing your app is not necessory, You can choose any license for your app. But open source is recommended